# combo box .text properties display wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

[image]

I have one of the screen design as in the above image

Now you can see I got fill up product series approver 1 and approver 2 and so on.

[image]

But I keep getting empty value from approver 1.text  or approver2.text.
What is the cause of this error??

Comment: try `approver1.GetText()`

Comment: Share related ASPX markup and more code behind

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem. cause of postback.
it will trigger SelectedIndexChanged event

```
  protected void CbxRejDocNum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    LoadDocumentDataRej(); // for load information
  }
```

i remove the event during Capture Phase

```
 CbxRejDocNum.SelectedIndexChanged -= new 
 System.EventHandler(CbxRejDocNum_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can get combo box's selected text "comboBoxName.SelectedItem.Text"

Answer (score -1):

I presume you're using `ASPxClientComboBox`.
You can get the text via [GetText()](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientComboBox.GetText) method.

```
var text = mycombobox.GetText();
```